Diet plan software recommendation
This is related: Diet planner software
However, the suggestion is for a web based solution, and tracking appears to be a central concept here.
I'm not interested in web software, nor tracking. I'm looking for a recommendation for a local application, for Linux, that features diet planning where each day of the week is scheduled beforehand, each meal is specified, and the software calculates the calories, vitamins, minerals, proteins, etc. This should be displayed graphically or so to give an overview of how close or far off the patient is from the ideal recommended intake (based on age, weight, gender, etc.).
I don't need support for use cases that include tracking what is actually eaten, I don't need smartphone support, or web support. If it also supports this also, that isn't a bad thing, but it isn't accepted if it isn't a local, traditional application.
